# Looking for curl or any other command to get the version number of an artifact belonging to particular release in nexus

Tags: rest, api, curl, nexus

For eg:

In my nexus repo - Temp-releases, under com/abc/temp/trial-platform-rpm, I have various folders like

```
6.1.7.0.34
6.1.8.1.3
7.0.0.0.568
7.0.1.0.89
7.0.2.0.544
```

So my script will provide the first 4 digits (For eg: if the branch selected is 7.0.2.0) then from nexus, I need to find latest version for this release (which is 7.0.2.0.544)

```
INPUT
7.0.2.0
```

```
OUTPUT
7.0.2.0.544
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl command is as below and provide the version in grep :

curl -s "https://nexussite/nexus/service/local/repositories/Core-deloy/content/com/abc/item/item-portal-rpm/maven-metadata.xml" | grep ".*" | sort | uniq | sed -e "s#\(.*\)\(\)\(.*\)\(\)\(.*\)#\3#g"| grep 7.0.1.0 | tail -n1""